# Copy a directory of files to the install directory as part of install

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, installation

I am sure this is posted somewhere, but I can't get the right combination of keywords to find it.  Please indulge me.

I am using VS2013 and using c# and .net 4.5 although most of that is not relevant.
I have an application that needs two sub directories under the directory where the .exe lives.The directories are x86 and x64. They have one file in each of them. Most of the files I need to end up in the directory with the .exe I just add to the project and mark them as Always Copy to Output.  That gets them there.  The two directories cannot be added to the project that way.

How can I build the install to copy the two directories with the application install.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you trying to do that via an installer Project inside VS 2013?

Comment: Yes. I was using the wizard, but I am open to other options. Install shield will do the directory, but will not handle the report viewer prerequisite. Therefore I would like to do it from within VS.